# When having a p2p webtrc connection, how to use different resolutions for the video call and the photo capture?

Tags: webrtc, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm working on a p2p webtrc video call between HoloLens2 and PC. I also need to support the capturing of photos(and send photos to the server). Now the video and photo can be supported with a resolution of 2272x1278, but I need the photo resolution of 3904x2196(the highest value that HoloLens2 provides).

The problem is when I am trying to change the resolutions, I found I had no limit when the call continues.

I use [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui) to take a photo. And the WebcamSource based on MixedReality-WebRTC running on the SharedReadOnly mode. I thought of one way to solve this: shut the call down when taking a photo, and restart it after capturing finished. But the problem is

1. How can I set the mode to exclusive WebcamSource when just capturing the photo?
2. Can I make sure when the call had been shut down, the WebcamSource is released?

Or if there is another way to use different resolutions for the video call and the photo capture? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set the mode to exclusive WebcamSource when just capturing the photo?

No, SharingMode has hardcoded in the [UwpUtils](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/blob/master/libs/unity/library/Runtime/Scripts/Media/UwpUtils.cs#L37) and does not expose any API to access.

> Can I make sure when the call had been shut down, the WebcamSource is released?

To make sure dispose of audio and video tracks and media sources last, please reference the following code:

```
localAudioTrack?.Dispose();
localVideoTrack?.Dispose();
microphoneSource?.Dispose();
webcamSource?.Dispose();
```